# Python commands on OSS

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

I have extracted the python 2 package in OSS HP Non stop environment with the help of Network team. Does anyone know how to invoke python commands in OSS? If I try OSH it takes me to the Linux environment. 
When I try to access python its giving error as 
$Data21 APSUSR>Python
No such built in commands, functions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is the file I have referred for installation "NonStop Python 2 Programmers Guide.pdf"

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are trying to run python from the TACL prompt ("$Data21 APSUSER>") - if that is correct then you need to start an OSS shell process first and run python from there. Either use the osh command standalone or logon to an OSS shell rather than a TACL one when you connect to the NonStop.

To answer your question, you should be able to just use python in the normal fashion from the OSS shell prompt:

```
/home/as: python hello.py
Hello Christie
```

Remember that OSS is case-sensitive, so you need "python" not "Python".
If the guess about the TACL prompt above is wrong, please cut/paste what you see.

Andy

Comment: I was able to access python in OSS. Thank you.